# Pulling CSS data using getElementById

Tags: javascript, css, getelementbyid

I'm trying to pull CSS data out of an element but I am hitting a wall for some reason. I have been staring and trying to tweak the same line of code for an hour and I keep getting undefined or NaN.

Here is the abbreviated js:

```
var newVar = document.getElementById("cssItem").style.top;
```

The css:

```
#cssItem {
position:   absolute;
top:        100px;
left:       100px;
width:      600px;
height:     400px; 
}
```

Again, every time I log newVar it comes back undefined or NaN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Node.style` only works for inline styles. If you want to get the rendered style, use this:

```
var newVar = window.getComputedStyle( document.getElementById("cssItem") ).top;
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q93B6/